# PHP different results for mysql_query and pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to convert a `mysql_query` to `pdo` equivalent

My table structure is (removed unrelated columns -  the one needed for my question is `other_id`) :

```
CREATE TABLE `temp_table` (
  `id` int(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `other_id` int(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And the data it has:

```
-----------------
| id | other_id |
-----------------
| 1  |      123 |
-----------------
| 2  |        0 |
-----------------
| 3  |      456 |
-----------------
| 4  |        0 |
-----------------
```

The previous database query was :

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM temp_table WHERE other_id = '{$other_id}'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $db)
return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

The query is called with `$other_id` as `NULL` ("null" in php and not string or anything).

**Result mysql_query** : This gives my values `2,4`

PDO equivalent code :

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM temp_table WHERE other_id = :other_id";
$sth = $dbConnection->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindValue(":other_id", $other_id);
$sth->execute();
return $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

**Result PDO :** This gives no values at all.

This is weird issue which I have not encountered before (since I am more java developer and recently touched PHP after few years).

As a workaround I had to put below line to return `2,4` as result from pdo output, but want to understand more about the difference mentioned above.

```
$sth->bindValue(":other_id", empty($other_id) ? 0 : $other_id);
```

I also tried `$sth->bindValue(":other_id", $other_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);` which did not help

Comment: What difference would that make? UPDATE : Just changed to `bindParam` still same issue

Comment: Technically `0` is *NOT NULL* in the database so if you're passing in `NULL` for `$other_id` it *shouldn't* match ... I'm more confused by why it *used* to work under the `mysql_` extension - it shouldn't have done.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but instead of `empty($other_id) ? 0 : $other_id` you could also just do `(int)$other_id`

Comment: In the first example (non-PDO), `$other_id` is converted to a string (which evaluates to `other_id = ''`). That's actually the same as `0` here. The second example is passing `NULL`, which `!= 0`.

Comment: @BenM That explains it! Thanks ;)

Comment: @CD001 Yeah, retracted my remarks because of that.

Comment: Hope you can take the opportunity to use InnoDB instead of the creaky old MyISAM database engine.

Answer (score 4):

This is not an issue with the `mysql_` vs PDO difference, but rather with type-juggling.

In the first non-PDO example, `$other_id` is being converted to a string in the query, so your query looks like this:

```
SELECT id FROM temp_table WHERE other_id = '';
```

MySQL treats an empty string the same as `0` for fields of numeric type during queries, so your query is actually correctly matching two records.

In the PDO example since you're passing `$other_id` (which is `null`), your query is bound as follows:

```
SELECT id FROM temp_table WHERE other_id = NULL;
```

MySQL does not treat `0` as `NULL`, so the queries that you're sending are actually not the same.

Answer (score 4):

> This is weird issue which I have not encountered before.

There is nothing weird here.

When `$other_id` is `NULL` the first query becomes:

```
SELECT id FROM temp_table WHERE other_id = ''
```

Because the type of the `other_id` column is numeric, the provided value (the empty string) [is converted to the number `0`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html) and there are two matching rows.

On the other hand, the query sent through PDO is equivalent to:

```
SELECT id FROM temp_table WHERE other_id = NULL
```

Not only that there are no `NULL`s in the table, but this query never returns any row, even if there are rows having `NULL` in the column `other_id`. (The correct way to select the rows having `NULL` in `other_id` is to use the [`IS NULL` operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null)).